# Polimorfismo en Java sin reemplazar el metodo de clase padre

Tags: java, c++

Como puedo aplicar polimorfismo a una subclase pero si reemplazar la implemetacion de dicho metodo, siendo que deseo aumentar mas funcionalidad a mi metodo y no reemplazarlo.
Esto en C++ es muy comun o yo suelo hacerlo mucho pero ahora en Java me veo envuelto en la duda.

incluyo codigo demostrativo de C++

```cpp
class persona{
 private:
    string name;
    int edad;
 public:
   virtual void setter(){
    cin>>name;
    cin>>edad;
  }
};

class profesor: public persona{
 private:
   string profesion;
 public:
  void setter(){
    persona::setter();
    cin>>profesion;
  }
};
```

como puedo lograr hacer eso en Java.

Comment: Hola!Recuerda que las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para refrescar el funcionamiento el sitio . 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En java, para referirte a un método de la clase padre, se utiliza la palabra reservada `super`. Entonces, para extender su funcionalidad simplemente usas `super.metodoQueQuieresDelPadre()` dentro del método que estés extendiendo. Es prácticamente igual a lo que expones en tu código de c++. Por ejemplo:

```
class Persona{
    public void saludar() {
        System.out.println("¡Hola! ¡Soy una persona!");
    }
};

class Profesor extends Persona{
    @Override
    public void saludar() {
        super.saludar();
        System.out.println("Trabajo como profesor :)");
    }
}
```

En Java, todos los métodos no estáticos son virtuales de forma predeterminada, por lo que con solo declararlos con la misma firma en el hijo ya lo estás sobrescribiendo. No obstante, conviene anotarlos con `@Override` para hacer la sobreescritura de manera explícita y tener cierta ayuda del IDE.